# Haskell/lambda calculus types example

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

Suppose that the Haskell or lambda calculus presents the following function types:

A -> B -> C

(A -> B) -> C

How are these two different?

Comment: The first is equivalent to A -> (B -> C). Was that your question?

Answer (score 4):

The first is a function from `A` to a (a function from `B` to `C`). The second is a function from (functions from `A` to `B`) to `C`. The first "takes two arguments" the second "takes one argument". The first is a normal function, the second is a "higher order function".

Comment: Both are higher order functions.

Comment: Technically true, they also both take a single argument, though. Perhaps I should scare quote "higher order function".

Comment: Yeah, fair enough :) . People take "higher order function" to mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: I've tended to see "currying" and "HOF" as being thought of as very different components that play together nicely instead of a natural consequence of basing a language on lambda calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two example functions with your types that will help you figure out how these are different:

```
valatzero :: Num a => (a -> t) -> t
valatzero f = f 0

plus :: Num a => a -> a -> a
plus x y = x + y
```